# I need to call an Url from a python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

my search found solutions to more complex url calls but i couldnt find a simple one.

i have this setup: axis IP loudspeaker and rasperry pi. several buttons are connected to the GPIO of the rasperry which should trigger audio files on the axis loudspeaker via a simple url when pressed

example
http://192.168.10.204/axis-cgi/playclip.cgi?location=emergency.mp3&repeat=0&volume=22

by entering this url in a browser the loudspeaker plays the file emergency.mp3 at volume 22

### now i started putting together the script

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import urllib
import sys
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

while(True):
    if (GPIO.input (11) == True):
        response = urllib.urlopen('http://192.168.10.204/axis-cgi/playclip.cgi?location=emergency.mp3&repeat=0&volume=22').read()
```

---

when i push the button this is what i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "axis.py", line 13, in <module>
    response = urllib.urlopen('http://192.168.10.204/axis-cgi/playclip.cgi?location=emergency.mp3&repeat=0&volume=22').read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 364, in open_http
    return self.http_error(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 377, in http_error
    result = method(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 701, in http_error_401
    errcode, errmsg, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 386, in http_error_default
    raise IOError, ('http error', errcode, errmsg, headers)
IOError: ('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x7669f738>)
```

Comment: `Unauthorized`. Is `192.168.10.204` a web server? Can you get to that link in a browser? Do you have authentication turned on for the web server?

Comment: you pointed my into the right direction... the problem was that i didnt set up authentication... had given credentials in the browser once at the beginning and the loudspeaker didnt ask for it anymore afterwards. the script on the other hand needed to provide username and password. thank you

Comment: glad I could help. Post what you did as an answer if you feel so other people running into the same issue can figure it out. Welcome to the Stack!

Answer (score 0):

If the website you are using requires a user agent, which is highly possible if it is not yours, you need to specify a user agent for example: 
`

```
url='YOUR URL'
headers={}
headers['User-Agent']='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17'
req=urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
resp=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
data=resp.read()
```

`

Comment: you pointed my into the right direction... the problem was that i didnt set up authentication... had given credentials in the browser once at the beginning and the loudspeaker didnt ask for it anymore afterwards. the script on the other hand needed to provide username and password. thank you!